# How do I call a function repeatedly?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

By means of the module `multiproproccessing.dummy`, I want to perform the function `getData()` 10 times. However, the `print` function is only called once.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

print("Begin")

import itertools
import urllib.request
import time

def getData():
        print("Do something...")

t0 = time.time()
with ThreadPool(10) as pool:
    results = pool.map_async(getData(), iterable=(x for x in range(10)))
    
t1 = time.time()
totalTime = t1-t0
print ("Total Cyclic time: ", totalTime)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `pool.map_async(getData, ...)`?

Comment: Yes i do @quamrana.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `getData()` before passing it into `map_async`, which passes in its results, instead of passing in the function itself.

Change `getData()` to `getData` and you should be OK.

```py
    results = pool.map_async(getData, ...)
```

Comment: Allright that sound reasonably. One more thing, what do I need to fill at ... ? argument: 'iterable

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't want to re-type what you had in your question. I believe you'll hit at least one more bug (getData doesn't take arguments, but you're tying to pass in the values from your iterable as the arguments).

Comment: the function pool.map_async needs the following arguments: func, iterable. That's is why I coded it that way. I dont know what to fill 'iterable' with. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html